# Image is falling out of container, CSS issue?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm stuck on this pretty simple problem and I know there must be a simple solution but I don't know what to do. I'm sure it is a CSS issue since everything else is functioning fine. Here is the page in question-

And the code used for the page

CSS:

```
div.fadehover {
    position: relative;
}


img.a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z - index: 10;
}

img.b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

HTML/JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>
            jQuery Hover Effect
        </title>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'>
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery("img.a").hover(

                function() {
                    jQuery(this).stop().animate({
                        "opacity": "0"
                    }, "slow");
                }, function() {
                    jQuery(this).stop().animate({
                        "opacity": "1"
                    }, "slow");
                });
            });
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/mouseover.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="fadehover">
            <img src="pre.jpg" alt="" class="a" />
            <img src="post.jpg" alt="" class="b" />
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: To quote myself from another comment: `is your tab key broken?`

Comment: What's the problem? The page is behaving as it should....absolutely positioned elements aren't included in container size calculations.

Comment: @JamWaffles - On the contrary, those *are* tabs.

Comment: If you need help and want to have a demo (which is a great idea), please refrain from URL shorteners and setup a http://jsfiddle.net instead. `:)`

Comment: @Jared What tabs are you referring to? I don't see any in the above question.

Comment: @JamWaffles - Click the `edit` link; the tabs are collapsing into four spaces.

Comment: @JamWaffles - I'm sure there's a plausible reason, but I wish SO would fix it to work the way you would think it would. `:)`

Comment: @Jared The one thing I'd really like is to have the tab key be contained within the editor, instead of having to mash my spacebar all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on jsfiddle. I'm new to SO so didn't know how to properly format code in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because the two images have absolute positions the div.fadehover is failing to get a height. So adding `height: 700px;` to the div.fadehover class in the css seems to fix the problem. (From my point of view anyway :)

Comment: That fixed it!! I can't beleive I was struggling with this. Thanks.